# POE to WiFi adaptor

Tags: wifi, poe

I have an outdoor camera that needs POE.  There is power and WiFi, but no ability to run ethernet.  Is there a device that can connect to the WiFi and provide POE (power and data) to the camera?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its what your looking for, but PoE power injectors exist.

You plug one end into the RJ45 port.
The other end goes into an outlet.

Comment: Yes, that's half a solution, and if I could find a simple device that connects to a wireless network and serves the data out of an ethernet port, a power injector like you describe would presumably provide the full functionality I'm looking for.